# jqGrid and metadata

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid which loads very nice (thanks Oleg), however I load flat data from a database table which also contains id's which I want to merge on the interface with the metadata there available

So I have a bunch of variables like:
      var strMeta = [{id:35,label:"Russia",labelLocal:"Россия",pid:"33"},  {id:36,label:"Moldavia",labelLocal:"Молдавия",pid:"33"}]

In the jqGrid are id's like 35 and 36.
Now what I want to do is when the jqGrid page loads (so only for the page and not the entire data) it will match with that specific column so I get something like "[35] Россия" instead of "35", anybody ever tried to do this or have any idea how to do this?

for a form object I do this already however I cannot get this to work on the jqGrid

```
            $.each(_Columns, function (x, it) {
                if (i == it.name) {
                    var dataid = it.dataid;
                    if (dataid !== "") {
                        $.each(strMeta, function (y, arr) {
                            if (arr.id == item) {
                                alert(arr.label);
                                var _item = "[" + item + "] " + arr.labelLocal;
                                if (arr.labelLocal === "") {
                                    _item = "[" + item + "] " + arr.label;
                                    $("#" + i).val(_item);
                                }
                                return;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
```

I know here the textbox names, however this is in a jqGrid a little different as I understood the rowid is being added to the name of the column

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, but your question contains many unclear things. For example how you fill the grid? Which `datatype` you use in jqGrid? Do you use `data: strMeta`, `datastr: strMeta`, ...? Where is the code which you posted executed? The code contains many undefined variables (like `item`, `i`, `_Columns`). Why you can't just modify the values of every `id` property of elements of `strMeta` array? You need just make a loop and modify the `id` property of every element.

Comment: Hello Oleg, to answer your unclear things, I get the data first into the grid with a webservice simuliar like this: url:     'dataServices/objects.asmx/InvokeData'
        , postData: JSON.stringify({ q: "med&1:11:1;pid;112:name:38" }) //"med&1:11:2;name;b:name:1", {pageid}:{tableid}:{filter}:{order}:{customerid}
Then the first page I want to access several columns to add additional data there as above described. The code I posted is a seperate function which I run after the whole page is loaded and some data is being added to the boxes. I want to modify every row in the first page.

Comment: However not being able to access each row in a loop

Comment: However not being able to access each row in a loop. in the code "_Columns" represent the name and the main id within the strMeta, "strMeta" I use just as a store for all the metadata which I use whole over the page. I just want to be able to loop through the visual page before its displays through different columns, so I need to get each row (page I have 10 rows) and column country_id (which now shows 35, but want to make it [35] moldavia)

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand your problem. A lot of questions will be cleared if you include the JavaScript code which creates the grid. So it seems that you use `datatype: "json"` to load data. **Do you use `loadonce: true`?** I still don't understand *where* (in which callback) you execute the code fragment which you posted. I don't full understand what you need, but if you need modify server response *before* the data will be used to fill the grid you can use `beforeProcessing` callback.